# location.pathname

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to add a class to a menuepoint if one path is selected.

It would be easy if every site was its own `.php`/`.html` file, however everything is ruled in **one** `.php` file and everything is navigated over actions (`?action=main`, `?action=userinformation`).

I am searching for an alternative to get this work with the path **and** the action.

```
if (location.pathname == "/index.php") {
    $("#main1").addClass("mainActive");
} else if (location.pathname == "/index.php?action=other") {
    $("#main2").addClass("mainActive");
}
```

Comment: Use PHP to read the `action` from the querystring then set the class on the appropriate element.

Comment: `location.search` contains the GET params string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`location.pathname` doesn't include the query string. But you can combine it with `location.search`:

```
var path = location.pathname + location.search;
//            "/index.php"   + "?action=other"

if(path === "/index.php?action=other") {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use like;

```
var s = location.search;
if (s === "" || s === "?" || s.indexOf("?action=main") > -1)
    // main active
else if (s.indexOf("?action=userinformation") > -1)
    // userinformation active
// ... and so on
```